# Putting two circuits on one breaker to avoid a shared neutral

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

How can I correct the neutral shared with breaker 1 and 2. I'm hoping I can pigtail these two circuits to one breaker.

One circuit is for the 2nd (10'x10') and 3rd (10'x12') bedroom. The 2nd bedroom has a ceiling fan with LED lights and a gaming pc the 3rd bedroom has a ceiling fan with LED lights and occasional use of a curling iron.

The other circuit I want to combine with it has the living room and kitchen lights and one outlet in the living room. There's ten 8W LED can lights and a TV on the outlet, the outlet is behind a wall mounted TV so nothing else can easily be plugged in.

Is it acceptable to combine these or do I need to make it a MWB circuit.

[image: panel label]
[image: panel]

Comment: If the curling iron and gaming PC are in use at the same time, it's likely to cause a breaker trip, _especially_ on a 15A circuit.

Comment: Never had a trip, probably because curling iron in the morning and gaming in the evening.

Comment: Wouldn't a breaker trip be better than putting 30A on the neutral?  Why does the question lean to joining them together rather than simply swapping some breakers around to make this an MWBC or, since you appear to have conduit, pulling another neutral to wherever these circuits diverge in the walls?

Comment: Why does the question lean to joining them together? Because I would only be adding 1 amp to an existing circuit and it would free up space for another breaker on a panel that's almost full.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shared neutrals are still code compliant today. Why are you concerned about a shared neutral? With the breakers on different legs looking at the age of the panel handle ties are not even required (but a good idea). you have the full ampacity of the circuit like it should. If you pig tail (it is allowed in the panel) the 2 onto 1 breaker now you would have 1/2 the ampacity for each room and more likely to trip. I ask because you say correct it. See NEC 2020 210.4 there are even pictures that have been in the code books for years, handle ties required in 2008 earlier in some jurisdictions.
Edit:
Pulled up on my computer so I could see things better, the way to fix this is to turn breaker 1 off and pull the wire off ant take it to #4 turn 4 off remove wire land the one from #1.
Pull that wire down to the bottom it looks like it comes in down there and should have enough slack to put on #1 then the panel would be safer, if the one from 4 is not long enough wire nut a piece to make it reach.
As I mentioned in the comments this is not an upgrade but panel “balancing” and fixing something that was not done correctly in the beginning (code did not specify back then) later versions became more specific until handle ties were required.

Comment: Right now though, breaker #1 and breaker #2 are on the same bus. The OP would have to change one feed to the other bus. Would that be considered an upgrade requiring handle ties?..+1

Comment: Not considered an upgrade,  but good question,+ it is totally acceptable and even required in some cases to move breaker locations if the hots are not long enough to swap sides 2 & 3 add a piece of wire to these I could not read the panel card and did not realize 1/2 was breaker numbers , still a quick fix no permits required because the panel is being balanced per code.

Comment: My concern is I plan on selling the house in a few years and I want to eliminate anything that could get flagged. If it's not a code violation then I'm ok with just moving the breaker so they're not on the same bus.

Comment: Goose you are not adding circuits, I updated my answer after viewing on a big screen it looks like the wire on #4 will reach around to #1  both 15 amp pulling the wire around is easier than dragging a breaker.

Comment: + You mean swap #1 and #4?  That would be ideal as it would put both MWBC elements adjacent (in 2-4) and ready for a handle-tie.  I would still do the handle-tie @PlatinumGoose.

Comment: Yes looking at the pic on my computer I loose 4 but it looks to have some slack and entrance on the bottom.

Comment: I'd worry more about frying the neutral now than about getting "flagged" in a few  years by a freakishly thorough inspector.

Comment: @Ed Beal #4 exits right in the middle on the bottom and it has some slack so it should reach #1. Harper it looks like I can get a handle tie for those breakers so I'll do that.

Comment: That would be a great option and yes they make handle ties, for years  we used a 6 penny nail cut off but today that would get flagged by most inspectors.